# NStextfield show Null placeholder (ie empty string) rather than showing 'No Selection' using Core data. Apple bug?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

How to remove the pesky "No Selection" from NSTextfield (and other NSView subs)

That may have something to with xcode

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Dec/msg00427.html
http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Dec/msg00440.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just a case of setting the *No Selection Placeholder* in the *Bindings Inspector* of IB?

[image]

Comment: SWEEEEEEEEEEET. Thanks a lot. How was that one missed: Looking for complexity when simplicity will do.